# Need to duplicate text in each line and add equal sign and prefix to it

Tags: vim

This is my text:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I would like it to be this text instead:

```
xxx = C.xxx
yyy = C.yyy
zzz = C.zzz
```

Is this possible to do in Vim?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can also use the simpler form:

```
:%s/.*/& = C.&
```

Comment: Awesome.  Slight fix: `:%s/.*/& = C.&/`.  Just added closing `/`.

Comment: @mpettis not needed at all if you don't have flags :-D It is surely more complete, but I left aside here for brevity

Comment: I need something like this for multiple lines: `%string%` into `string = %string%`

Answer (score 8):

Type this:

```
:%s/\(.*\)/\1 = c.\1/g
```

Breakdown:

- `%` - work on all lines
- `\(.*\)` - capture all the characters in a group ("group 1")
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g` - do a string substitution
- `\1` in the replace pattern - refer to the matched group

Comment: you don't need either `^` or `$`.

Comment: Depending on whether or not the content to be duplicated is actually at the start of the line, it might be handy to stuff `\s*\zs` right after the first `/` so that leading whitespace is preserved.

Comment: It helps me to get my replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text, then press `:` and type

```
s/\(.*\)/\1 = C.\1/
```