# duplicate several parts of a line in vim/bash

Tags: bash, vim

I need to change multiple strings in a given format in vim/bash: 
actual i/p: `%localdate%,%localtime%,%uptime%` 
desired o/p: `localdate=%localdate%,localtime=%localtime%,uptime=%uptime%`

There are 100s of such variables which needs to be changed in the file. Pls suggest the approach in bash/vim.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: yes, i tried few things but couldn't get it going. Before asking I referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098364/need-to-duplicate-text-in-each-line-and-add-equal-sign-and-prefix-to-it/7099631#7099631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way

```
:%s/\(%\(\w*\)%\)/\2=\1/g
```

**Explanation :**

```
\(%\(\w*\)%\)   -- Grouping the pattern  "%localdate%"
(\w*\)          -- Grouping the pattern  between the %string% line "localdate" only
\2=\1           -- Print the matched pattern  group 2 and group 1 like "localdate=%localdate%"
```

**Output :**

```
localdate=%localdate%,localtime=%localtime%,uptime=%uptime%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {myvar=substr($i, 2, length($i)-2); printf("%s=%s,", myvar,$i)}print ""}' test.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```